# Why are Mozilla Firefox speedtest results consistently <300 Mbps when Google Chrome is >700 Mbps?

Tags: networking, firefox, browser

Speedtest.net results using Google Chrome are consistently 700+ Mbps, but no matter what I do I can’t get Firefox to go over 300 Mbps (connecting to the same server).

I get the same results with Waterfox and Pale Moon and get the same results when I run Firefox in Safe Mode. Does anyone know why this is happening?

I don't have a Firewall or Anti-Virus software enabled.

Comment: What other factors have you controlled for (e.g., tested all in safe mode)?

Comment: My experience with FireFox is really bad related to the overall performance. But in this specific case... What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: Looks like no one answered your question. I have same problem, gigabit (fiber) internet, and mozilla is < 300 , chrome > 700.

Comment: I have the same problem. Not sure what is causing it. Chrome I can get 950 Mbps. Firefox does not get more than 300 in average. Same results in Pale Moon. Using Windows 7.